# load data in mysql and avoid duplication of records

Tags: mysql, perl, date

I am running the following code in my perl file:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(columns..., @var, morecolumns...)
SET datecolumn = str_to_date(@var, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

I have 2 questions:

1. when I run the perl file, I get the following error. Does that mean I have to add a field 'var' into my table in the DB?

   > Global symbol "@var" requires explicit package name at process.pl line 37.
   >   Execution of process.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
2. If for any reason I have to reload the data from the .csv files and run this command again, it adds the new records as duplicates. How can I edit the above code to avoid duplication of records?

UPDATED relevant code from Perl:

```
 my $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fname' INTO TABLE $tname FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (trade_dt,t_id,....open_int);";
 print $sql,"\n"; #date is going in as '0000-00-00'
  $dbh->do($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

this is what it shows in mySQL

```
mysql> select max(trade_dt) from test;
+---------------+
| max(trade_dt) |
+---------------+
| 0000-00-00    |
+---------------+
1 row in set (0.04 sec)
```

My understanding was that I needed to add the `SET trade_dt=str_to_date()` to get the date into my DB as `yyyy-mm-dd`. In the .csv file that I upload into the DB,the date is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`

Also, if it helps, this is how trade_dt is declared in mySQL table, test:

```
trade_dt date NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message in the first question means that Perl is interpreting the `@var` in this string as the global Perl array names `@var`, not as a SQL variable. It also means that you have said `use strict` at the top of your program, which is great!

A fix is to escape the special `@` character in the string:

```
(columns..., \@var, morecolumns...)
SET datecolumn = str_to_date(\@var, '%d/%m/%Y');
```

Comment: I declared `my @var;` and then escaped the `@` with the \. it gives me no error but it inserts the date as `0000-00-00`

Comment: @user1155299 Why on earth would you *both* declare the variable *and* escape it? That makes no sense. You have to do either or, depending on whether `@var` is a perl or mysql variable.

Comment: I believe it is a mysql variable. I am new to this, so I have made a mistake. I'd appreciate your suggestion on how to fix it.

Comment: @user1155299 No one can tell you how to fix it if they don't know how it's broken. You need to show your code.

Comment: ok, let me post my relevant Perl code. It seems like I don't need the @var.

Comment: just updated the initial post with the relevant code. Hope I laid it out better this time.

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, load data into a temporal table and then with a cursor, read the rows on the temporal and insert them in the real table avoiding duplicates with some logic code (where condition, if exists structure control, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a "REPLACE" instead of an "INSERT"? If not, then can you empty the table prior to doing your insert?

I have to empty a table prior to my main INSERT in a java program I use, since I don't care about the old data...

Answer (score 0):

The error `Global symbol @var..` comes from perl, and means your variable `@var` is not declared in the current scope. Assuming it is properly used, you can declare it with `my @var`. If it is some non-perl variable, you'll need to single quote the string to avoid variable interpolation. It is hard to say what you should do, since you show nothing of your code. For example:

```
my $query = q#LOAD DATA INFILE 'file_name'
INTO TABLE tbl_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
(columns..., @var, morecolumns...)
SET datecolumn = str_to_date(@var, '%d/%m/%Y');#;
```

Note that `q()` will take alternative delimiters, depending on your need, for instance `#`, and will prevent variable interpolation in the string.

If it is a perl variable, you should probably use [placeholders](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#Placeholders_and_Bind_Values) and the [DBI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI) module (or similar) for added safety. The `@var` array, if inside a double quoted string, will be expanded and space padded (if `$"` is set to default), which may not be exactly what you want. E.g.:

```
my @var = ("foo", "bar", "baz");
print "@var";
```

Will print `foo bar baz`.

Comment: I declared it as you suggested, no error now, but it inserts `0000-00-00`

Comment: @user1155299 Well, is it a perl variable? If it is not, then of course you should not declare it, as it will insert a blank and false value into your code.

Comment: well, I am basically following this example from the mySQL website: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,136269,136273#msg-136273, and it seems like I made a mistake in declaring it as a Perl variable. what is the correct way to do it. I have date in my .csv as 22/01/2012 and I want it to go in as 2012-01-22.

Comment: @user1155299 Well, if you don't know where `@var` comes from, then I cannot tell you. Perhaps you should show more of your perl code.

Comment: any thoughts - all I want is the date being inserted into the DB as %Y-%m-%d

Comment: @user1155299 You do not use any date in the code as far as I can see. The only variable in the string is `$fname`. If you read the documentation for DBI you will find some examples of how to read data from a file.

Comment: trade_dt is the date that is being inserted using LOAD data...$fname is only the filename.